# Unknown device mac address listed in switch table on start out

Tags: switch, switching, mac-address, packet-tracer, bridge

After playing a little bit with a topology randomly created in packet tracer, I figured out that the switch (Switch0) stores a unknown device mac address on start out, wich I think that it belongs to a indirectly connected PT-Bridge interface. (See topology)
I dont know if I am right. But the Switch0 also stores the mac address interface from the other switch (Switch1) on start out. I can check it by seeing this mac address in the Switch1 interface (Fa0/1).
I have not chance to verify the bridge mac addesss to argue it, and I am not sure that bridge interfaces has got mac addresses assigned.
Any comment that will clear this issue will be welcome!
Thanks in advance!

Arturo.

[image]

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bridges learn MAC addresses from any frames they receive on an interface. Since you've connected it to a repeater hub, Switch0 learns all MACs to its north on Fa0/1.

Switches/bridges only use MAC addresses of their own for "higher" functions like management traffic, xSTP, CDP, LLDP. If Bridge0 has sent out anything like that on its west-facing port, its MAC address will show up in Switch0's MAC table. Otherwise, the MAC address belongs to one of PC0-PC7.